# How does datadog analyse the trace path to define the path group?

Tags: datadog, apm

I use datadog to monitor my application and I use the APM which sends everything to Datadog automatically.

For a specific endpoint, I have a strange behaviour:

Sometimes my traces are displayed like this: `http/path_group : /films/actor_id/notes` (with actor_id is different per actor)

And sometimes, they are displayed like: `http/path_group : /films/?/notes`

I want all traces displayed like this: `http/path_group : /films/?/notes`

Some information:

- language: kotlin
- java version 19
- apm: via datadog java agent